# How to set an environment variable for docker-compose in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, docker-compose

I cannot seem to find a way to set an environment variable that can be used in docker-compose in Intellij (Ultimate 2017.3 macos).
If I add a .env file to the folder in which docker-compose.yml resides, then it is not picked up by Intellij. Also if I do 'export MYVARIABLE=foo' in a terminal it is not picked up by the Intellij docker plugin.
Docker and docker-compose work fine both within or outside Intellij, the only thing is this environment variable substitution does not work in Intellij.

It keeps on saying:
The MYVARIABLE variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.

In my docker-compose.yml I have a reference to ${MYVARIABLE} and outside Intellij it works fine.

Comment: Can you please add the compose file to the question?

Answer (score 2):

The **Docker-compose** run configuration will identify [environment files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) with the .env suffix if they are located in the same directory as the Docker Compose file.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/docker.html#using-docker-compose

Put `MYVARIABLE=test` to `.env` file.

In your `.env` file :

```
MYVARIABLE=test

NGINX_PORT=80
MYSQL_PORT=3306
ADMINER_PORT=8080
...
```

See https://github.com/codeliner/php-ddd-cargo-sample/ 's `docker-composer.yml` and `.env.dist`

In my case copy `.env.dist` to `.env`

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with an export

`export MYVARIABLE=test` in your terminal.

You can verify with the command `env | grep 'myvariable'`.

And in your compose file:

`environment:
     - MYVARIABLE=${MYVARIABLE}`

Comment: This works for me 'outside' of Intellij, meaning that I can execute in a terminal 'docker-compose up' and it works, but it does not work if I run docker-compose from the run/debug configurations in intellij itself.